# No sound on 12.04 (wubi)

Tags: 12.04, sound, wubi

I've been struggling with this for quite a while.
I have no sound at all (system sounds, login sound, rhythmbox, vlc, youtube etc.)

- The system detects my audio card (POD Studio UX2)
- I've tried 'sudo alsa force-reload', nothing.
- No sound through headphones either.
- I've checked everywhere, nothing is muted.
- System Settings > Sound > Test Sound also produces no sound

Note: POD Studio UX2 is an external audio card by Line6.

Can someone please help?

Comment: run `sudo alsamixer` and make sure that your device isn't muted.

Comment: I have already tried this, but I can't find a mute/unmute option http://i178.photobucket.com/albums/w247/morgan-bailey/Screenshot.png

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, everything looks correct. It shows you a `M` instead of a numeric value to indicate if a channel is muted. Do you have `pulseaudio` installed?

Comment: Yes, pulseaudio is installed. I don't know if that helps, but I can't actually mute anything in alsamixer (by pressing m)

Comment: I used to have problems with pulseaudio, you can try `sudo chmod -x $(which pulseaudio)`. After this restart. Might work, might not. To revert the change you can do `sudo chmod +x $(which pulseaudio)`

Comment: Tried it, messed up the sound even more (no card detected, no sound controls). And when I try the second command to revert, I get 'chmod: missing operand after +x'. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message.

Comment: That's all it says. And of course 'Try `chmod --help' for more information.'

Comment: All we did was remove the execute bit. You can try `sudo chmod 755 $(which pulseaudio)` That should revert the change. Sorry for  the problem caused.

Comment: No problem, I reinstalled anyway :)

Comment: Your sound is fine now?

Comment: Nope. As a last resort, I might enable the onboard card. Interesting thing though, when I reinstalled 12.04, I had sound for about a minute or two, then gone forever.

Comment: Any luck with another distro?

Answer (score 1):

Audio trouble with Ubuntu some common checks

-- If you are using a laptop, your laptop may have a keyboard function to manipulate your sound.
   Check that. Your laptop may have a keyboard control to mute, increase and decrease sound.
-- Please check your sound devices volumes are to a high level double click on the top right loudspeaker icon you will see a mixer
-- Please make common test from menu System->Preferences->Sounds

-- If you have two audio cards - please disable the on board audio card using BIOS setting, please check with this terminal command:

lspci | grep -i audio

-- Please be sure your pc are starting with the generic kernel press ESC at boot when you see the GRUB row then select the "kernel.... - generic" row
-- Please be sure all needed kernel modules are installed to make this check and install them:
  So open a Terminal from the menu Applications->Accessories->Terminal and type:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-ubuntu-modules-$(uname -r)

give your user password when requested, you don't see nothing when you type it, then press enter.

Then reboot your pc.

-- Be sure your user is member of audio group
Then open a Terminal from the menu Applications->Accessories->Terminal and type:

sudo adduser $(who am i | cut -d" " -f 1) audio
sudo chmod 660 /dev/snd/*

give your user password when requested, you don't see nothing when you type it, then press enter.

-- Please try to watch what audio cards are detected on your system please type:
asoundconf list

if more than one sound cards is detected by your system to set the default soundcard

asoundconf set-default-card PARAMETER

change PARAMETER with the name of a one detected sound card

-- Please try to delete making a backup copy of this conf files
mv .asoundrc .asoundrc_old
mv .asoundrc.asoundconf .asoundrc.asoundconf.old
sudo mv /etc/asound.conf /etc/asound.conf.old

Please take a look at this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=205449

-- Please try to discover if there are any process they are keeping the /dev/dsp locked
ps -edalf | grep -i dsp

kill them using this command:

kill -9 number_of_pid

---

If you microphone seems don't record your voice please open a terminal and type

alsamixer

and press tab to switch in view to [Capture] section, and then pressing space on mic and mic boost aid

If you are using Pulseaudio and you have some sound issue with sound apps please read  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=4928900

Hope this helps